# User unable to recieve messages from a specific sender, recipient_status = usermailbox.forwardable.resolver.createrecipientitems.40

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have a new user in an existing tenancy, who is unable to recieve emails from a sending domain external to the tenancy.

This has stopped them from being able to recieve a "Welcome to 'accounting package'" email, and as such, unable to do their job.

Message Trace logs indicate that the messages are being recieved by the sender, but not being delivered to the mailbox. The messages are also being flagged that the recipient_status is usermailbox.forwardable.resolver.createrecipientitems.40.
My research for this code all points to auto forwarding rule, however, there are none associated with the mailbox, or incoming domain.

The solution indicated here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/private-e-mails-appear-in-group-inbox/2d5e67a1-d187-43d4-a857-a63484269c54 does not bear any fruit, as there are no emails in the quarantine for the user.

Any assistance on finding the missing emails would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm here to narrow down this mail flow issue: 1. Did only the user in this tenancy encounter this issue? What about other users? 2. Could the same message deliver to the tenancy successfully if the sender is from another external domain? 3. What happens if you try to send a test email which has only one word or a short sentence?
Have you inspected the forward settings of the recipients?(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/configure-email-forwarding)

Comment: Besides, check if there is any inbox(Outlook) forward rule configured for these recipients' mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan_Wang. As stated in the original description, there are no fowarding rules on the maibox, either on the server, or on the local Outlook.

1. Just this user.
2. No idea, I don't control the external domain. It's an automated email from an accounting package.
3. See 2.

Comment: Could you find these emails in the following location? O365 Security and Compliance-Threat Management-Reviews(https://protection.office.com/quarantine)

Comment: No, the emails are not located in the quarantine.

Comment: I think you could ask for help from the following location and see if others have the same problem or solutions: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1